# I can't align my List

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have big problem i can't align my list, whenever i want to set padding or margin in css my background color just get bigger by px. i set in margin or padding. I will set picture so i can explain you better. What is best way to do this

```css
header{
  background: #304852;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: #585858 3px solid;
}
header a{
  font: 1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 40px;
}
header ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header li{
  /* float: left; */
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;

}

header nav{
  /* float: right; */
  
  text-align: right;
}
#logo{
  padding-top: 50px
}
```

```html
  <header>
    <div id="logo">

    <img src="C:\Users\Mihajlo\Desktop\retardirani mihajlo\mm2.png" width="200px" height="200px">
  </div>
        <nav>
      <ul>

        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) on the parent logo id and put your navigation inside that container all together then align the items in the center and space them around.

```css
header{
  background: #304852;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: #585858 3px solid;
}
header a{
  font: 1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
}
header ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header li{
  /* float: left; */
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;

}

header nav{
  /* float: right; */
  
  text-align: right;
}
#logo img{border-radius: 50%;}
#logo{
  padding: 50px 0;
  /*THIS WAS ADDED*/
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
 <header>
    <div id="logo">

    <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" width="200px" height="200px">
              <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
  </div>

</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

CSS

```
header{
  background: #304852;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: #585858 3px solid;
}
header a{
  font: 1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 40px;
}
header ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header li{
  /* float: left; */
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;

}

header nav{
  float: right;

  text-align: right;
}
#logo{
  float:left;
}

header.clearfix
{
  content:"";
  display: table;
  width:100%;
}
```

HTML

```
  <header class="clearfix">
    <div id="logo">

    <img src="C:\Users\Mihajlo\Desktop\retardirani mihajlo\mm2.png" width="200px" height="200px">
  </div>
        <nav>
      <ul>

        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

Pretty much the same code you have. make the logo and nav elements float and add a clearfix to header .

hope this helps..